# Possibilities for external database with MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

This question is quite general, however, i can not find a good answer for it.

What are the possibilities for using an external database with MS Access?

I see that MySQL can be used, but I would have to setup a ODBC connection and install drivers on every machine. The issue is that I have a software developed in MS Access that uses a lot of data, and it gets very slow at processing the data when i include a lot of data.

The software analyzes data from wind turbines, so it is used by different customers and it may contain a lot of different turbines with 50,000+ rows in each data set.

I would like these turbine data to be stored in a separate file that is pointed to by MS Access, so I include the software + whatever turbine data wanted.

As it is now, i have a lot of Access database files where the data is included in the software. It becomes impossible to keep track of - Especially when I do an edit to the source code of the software, which is do a lot these days.

Another issue is that the users may only have Access Runtime.

What are my options here? Is the best method to use the Access Link function?

Best regards, Emil.

Edit:

SQL's - Can they be combined? :

```
SELECT q_DataLimited.YAW001, q_DataLimited.YAW002
FROM q_DataLimited
WHERE (((q_DataLimited.YAW002)>Degree_dsp() And (q_DataLimited.YAW002)<Degree_dsp_high()));
```

And

```
SELECT Count(q_WindRose_PCU.YAW001) AS CountOfYAW0011
FROM q_WindRose_PCU;
```

Edit 2:

```
Public Degree As Long
Public Function Degree_dsp() As Long
Degree_dsp = Degree * 20
End Function
```

I have the degree as a counter outside the function in a form being:

```
For Degree = 0 To 17
DoCmd.OpenQuery "q_WindRose_PCU"
DoCmd.Close
Next Degree
```

Edit 3:
How to combine a query and the append of it to a table?

```
SELECT q_PowerBinned.Bin, Avg(q_PowerBinned.POW001) AS AvgOfPOW001, StDev(q_PowerBinned.POW001) AS StDevOfPOW001, Avg(q_PowerBinned.WSP001) AS AvgOfWSP001, StDev(q_PowerBinned.WSP001) AS StDevOfWSP001, Avg(q_PowerBinned.POW002) AS AvgOfPOW002, StDev(q_PowerBinned.POW002) AS StDevOfPOW002, Avg(q_PowerBinned.WSP002) AS AvgOfWSP002, StDev(q_PowerBinned.WSP002) AS StDevOfWSP002, Count(q_PowerBinned.Bin) AS CountOfBin
FROM q_PowerBinned
GROUP BY q_PowerBinned.Bin;
```

And then the append of the above to a table:

```
INSERT INTO t_Average_Stored ( Bin, PowAvg001, WindAvg001, PowAvg002, WindAvg002, n_samples, PowDev001, WindDev001, PowDev002, WindDev002 )
SELECT q_Average_Temp.Bin, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfPOW001, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfWSP001, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfPOW002, q_Average_Temp.AvgOfWSP002, q_Average_Temp.CountOfBin, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfPOW001, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfWSP001, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfPOW002, q_Average_Temp.StDevOfWSP002
FROM q_Average_Temp;
```

Comment: I think the best option is to not use Access.  It has a time and a place, but what you describe isn't it.

Comment: What do you suggest then? I would like to use the forms or at least create them in another system. A lot of calculations are done in it, it is not just like a regular customer database. A tool for data analysis, custom made for wind turbine performance...

Comment: I suggest a server side language such as .net, java, coldfusion, etc.  Then your application can be accessed with a web browser.

Comment: Oh, okay, that seems like a bigger task. I am a control engineer, not a programmer, so we would need to hire one then... So I may be stuck with Access... :p

Comment: It sounds like your current Access application is "monolithic", meaning that the data (tables) and the UI (forms, reports, ...) are all in the same file. You definitely want to split that into two parts: a "back-end" for the data tables and a "front-end" file for everything else (using linked tables in the front-end to manipulate the real tables in the back-end). As for the choice of back-end database engine, 50K rows is really not that big, so make sure that your current Access application has solid fundamentals (good table design, appropriate indexing, etc.) before changing the back-end db.

Comment: ... in other words, invest a bit of time (and/or money) to make sure that your current [database] engine is being used efficiently before sinking even more time (and/or money) into replacing the engine.

Comment: Hi Gord. I agree with your description. That is exactly the plan. I just kept the data inside the front end during development. So now that i have this done, i need the back-end. Hence the question! But you suggest just to link tables and keep it all in MS Access?

Comment: @EmilOlsen You could start with that. Then, if it turns out that some particular aspect of your application really does require you to use something other than the Access Database Engine to power the back-end then you could consider alternatives like SQL Server Express, MySQL, or similar. -- p.s. Note my use of the [@ symbol](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: @GordThompson Thank you, i will look into that. One additional question pops into my head, regarding efficiency of Access calculations: Is it faster to run an SQL through VBA than to have it in a query and use the "DoCmd.OpenQuery" and then close it again? I think my access i really slow at calculating for example the number of rows in a query, store that value in a table and then calculate in the next one. So i try to optimise the code, but i am not sure what is faster in Access....

Comment: @EmilOlsen For a given SQL statement there would almost certainly be no significant performance difference between `.Execute` and `.OpenQuery`.

Comment: Emil: Your recent edits to this question have strayed considerably from the original topic. You will get better results if you [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead of turning this question into a long rambling string of loosely-related inquiries.

Comment: Yes, perhabs we should take it to the chat. Nevertheless, i will remove the edits that are non related afterwards. I just want to make sure that SA see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see already a few suggestions in the comments, but I am going to answer the general question you posted. In short, the possibilities are endless.

MS Access, and Excel for that matter, have excellent external data tools that allow you to connect to almost any external data source and leverage on regular SQL-based databases or even use OLAP cubes to do your analysis. Access itself should be powerful enough to handle the data sets you mention. Even Access 2010 should be able to handle millions of records with relative ease.

MS Access does have a significant limitation, which is the 2GB file size. Once your database reaches 2GB, everything goes out the window and you are very likely to get data corruption. This is a well known issue, but I don't think you are anywhere near these limits.

Before considering an upgrade, though, there are a few things to suggest:

- Analyze the structure of your data and your database. Perhaps your tables are too big (lots of columns) and unnecessarily redundant. It may make sense to process the raw data you receive to split it into different tables that reduce the redundancy and improve performance.
- Look into indexing some key fields in your tables. This is heavily dependent on the type of analysis you do and what queries are most common. Read up on indexes and how to use them and explore some options with actual datasets. You may be surprised how queries that used to take minutes to run become almost instantaneous when the right indexes are created and maintained.
- Analyze your queries for performance. If I remember correctly, MS Access 2010 had a performance analyzer, which could improve your queries to make them run more efficiently.

If you have already looked into the items above and you decide you really need to take a step up, one fairly easy path (and inexpensive) is to install SQL Server Express, which you can download for free from Microsoft. Access was made to talk to SQL Server and the performance is many times better. You can run SQL Server Express in your personal pc and use it as a back-end for Access, or you could actually install it in a networked pc and use it as a server (behind a firewall, of course, NEVER connected to the Internet). In this setup you can access your data from several PCs.

One key thing to keep in mind once you start using Access as a front end, is that you want to push the processing to the back end, not keep it in Access. The best way to do this is to create what Access calls pass-through queries. These queries are written in the backend's native SQL language and are sent to the back end server for processing. Only the processed data comes back. If you don't do this, for example by creating the queries in the visual editor in Access instead, the raw data will be sent to Access and *then* Access will try to create your results. This, as you can imagine, can actually be a lot slower than your initial situation, so don't do it.

If you are not a SQL expert and need a visual editor, there is a tool that you can download from Microsoft: SQL-Server Management Studio Express. The query editor is not that different from Access and will allow you to create queries in a visual manner, but in Transact-SQL (the language of SQL Server). You can also manage your SQL Server Express with this tool and maintain your data in this manner (import, export, etc). You can create the SQL statements you need in this editor and then copy and paste into the pass-through queries in Access. The data will be available for you in the program you are familiar with, but with the power of a much bigger database engine behind the scenes.

Since I do not want to sound like a Microsoft shill, I definitely want to mention other options for external data that could be equally or even more powerful than SQL Server Express. The only reason I mentioned these is because you are already familiar with Microsoft products and the learning curve is a bit less steep. Also, most things should work together out of the box.

The first option that comes to mind is SQLite, which is a high performing database that is actually file-based. It is very small, yet very powerful and fast, and it is ideal for a locally based application like what you mention. There are also lots of graphical interfaces for SQLite and you can connect to it via ODBC from Access. Again, you want to run everything using pass-through queries and let SQLite pick up the load. SQLite is Open Source and it is free.

If you are keen on having "a real database server", then MySQL is probably the next step up. Also Open Source and free, it is very popular, which means lots of places to get support and different graphical interfaces to choose from.

Any search for Open Source Database will give you even more options to try and choose from.

One key thing to keep in mind: if you install any database server in your PC, *it will become a server*, and will start advertising its services in your local network or on the internet if you bring it to a local Starbucks. Be careful with that, learn how to start/stop the services in your PC, and make sure you turn them off when you are not behind a firewall. There are many exploits for different database servers and you will get quickly detected once your PC starts advertising its newly acquired abilities.

Just to close, there is no difference in the performance of Access and the runtime. Just the ability to edit the queries and so on. Whatever front end you create in Access, your users will be able to utilize in the same manner.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer! I will look into the different things mentioned. Regarding optimizing my queries, one of the tasks that takes a "longer time" is when i use the "count" function in the query. First, i move only 1 column to a new query, based on some limits. After this is updated, i create another query to do the "count", as i dont see how to combine these. Is there a smarter way to do similar?

Comment: As you know, any statements like GROUP BY, SUM, HAVING or COUNT take the most time to perform. Without looking at the data or the queries is not possible to tell for sure, but you might be able to combine these two steps into a single query. If your SQL is not very good, you can create the initial query in the visual editor and then edit it by hand. There is a button in Access that toggles between the visual editor and SQL statements, in the upper left corner. You may have seen it. You can usually tell Access how to run queries more efficiently

Comment: Yes, i know the SQL function you speak of. Let me just paste the two individual SQL's in the question, so you can have a look!

Comment: Yes, you can definitely combine these two statements, but I think the real problem is in the two functions you have defined there `Degree_dsp()` and `Degree_dsp_high()`. What happens is that Access might be calculating each function for each row before deciding whether to add it or not. Is it possible to calculate either function up front and then pass a single value to this query? That should save you lots of time. You can test it before making big changes by entering a numeric value in the query and then executing it. For example `(q_DataLimited.YAW002)>10`

Comment: The functions are just passing values from VBA. They are simply Degree_dsp() = Degree_dsp_VBA. The VBA value are updated in a loop that runs outside the query. In practice, what I have, is the degrees going from 0 to 360, jumping 20 each loop. So i have 17 loops. So i do the "count" query 17 times, move the value to a table each time, so i end up having a table of 0-20 deg = 4325 counts, 20-40, etc., i bet you get the big picture there.

Comment: I just tried changing the functions to integers directly, 20 and 40. That is not noticeable faster...

Comment: The combined statement would look like this `SELECT Count(*)
FROM q_DataLimited
HAVING (((q_DataLimited.YAW002>Degree_dsp()) And (q_DataLimited.YAW002<Degree_dsp_high())));`  Although as I mentioned before, if `Degree_dsp()` and `Degree_dsp_high()` are independent of the values of each row (it looks like they are), then you should calculate them upfront and pass a single value, which will make the query run faster.

Comment: Yes, it worked, and it was faster, i will use that now and see if it runs better in  total. Besides that, i am still not sure what you mean by passing a single value? I think that is what i am doing. look the edit 2 to see the function.

Comment: OK, we were typing at the same time. I see the problem, but I'm not sure why this is taking so long. Are there lots of columns in the q_DataLimited table, or is this another query? If so, you would benefit from building a temp table, similar to what you were doing here

Comment: q_Data_Limited holds 14 columns, around 40,000 rows. q_Data_Limited is a query of a table that holds also 14 colums but 400,000 rows. But that is really not a big deal, to make the q_Data_Limited query. Takes a few seconds...

Comment: The general problem is that it takes a lot of time to do rather simple queries. Most queries are made on the q_Data_Limited, with different criterias, based on the needs. But most of them takes about 5 seconds to execute. And i have at least 8 queries o 5 secs each loop, and the number of loops are 10-40, again based on what the user fills in. So i end up with 5-10 mins of execution time. After all of these are done, it calculates these previous mentioned degrees, 0-360 in 20 intervals, to create a so called wind rose, evaluating the number of measurements from a certain wind direction.

Comment: I'm glad it shaved a bit of time off from the query, although I have to admit I was hoping for more. It looks like you are already running well here. The only other things I would check at this point are 1) the types of the columns. It takes time to convert everything to the same type before comparing. Make sure they are the smallest type that will hold your data (don't use long if you can use int, etc).  2) Look into sorting the original table before running the query. And 3) create an index for YAW002.

Comment: Sorry, we keep typing past each other. I have a better picture of your problem now. I don't think it is realistic to get significant improvements from where you are now without really looking at everything and perhaps redesigning some parts of your process. I would start with the raw data, making sure it is stored in the most efficient manner and then look at the analysis you do in order to build the queries, views and forms from that starting point. Even then, you might already be squeezing as much as you can out of Access and you might benefit from a server backend. But can't tell for sure.

Comment: That was also my conclusion - Benefit from a back end server, hence the original question. But i am glad to have the improvements you mentioned so far. I will optimize all i can based on your suggestions, and let you know if any improvement occurs :) Thank you very much for your time sir!

Comment: In my search for reducing queries, some questions pops up. In general, i would like to reduce the number of queries that are updated. It seems to me that it is the actual task of updating a query that takes time, despite the size of it. So, i added an "Edit 3" in the question. I have a query followed by an append to a table. Can these be combined? I have this task multiple times.